Relate my program with a login function i have developed
My program opens the login function first and works well but i want  the login function to close when the login is succesful and open my main program you know but i don't know how to do it and i have searched in internet how  but can't figure it out
my main program:
(it's an encrypting program)
from tkinter import *
from sesion import ventana_inicio

from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

ventana_inicio()
raiz= Tk()

raiz.title("CODEC")
texto= StringVar()
raiz.resizable(False, False)
#raiz.iconbitmap("logo.ico")#

raiz.config(bg="dark green")

frame1= Frame()
frame1.pack()
frame1.config(bg="dark green")
frame1.config(width=650,height=400)

prompt= Label(text="Coloque el texto a encriptar", fg="black", font="Bold", bg="dark green")
prompt.place(x=230,  y=80)

def Encriptador():
    mensaje= cuadroinput.get()
    key= Fernet.generate_key()
    cifrar= Fernet(key)
    mensaje_cifrado = cifrar.encrypt(mensaje.encode())
   
    cuadroutput.delete(0, END) 
    cuadroutput.insert(0, mensaje_cifrado.decode())

cuadroinput=Entry(frame1, width=40)
cuadroinput.place(x=200 , y=120)

cuadroutput=Entry(frame1, width=70,  textvariable=texto)
cuadroutput.place(x=100, y=300)

boton=Button(raiz,text="Encriptar", command=Encriptador)
boton.config(fg= "black", bg="white", cursor="hand2")
boton.place(x=300, y=170)

raiz.mainloop()

this is my login system i have:
#CREANDO LOGIN CON PYTHON Y TKINTER.

#IMPORTAMOS LIBRERÍAS NECESARIAS.
from tkinter import *
import os


#CREAMOS VENTANA PRINCIPAL.
def ventana_inicio():
    global ventana_principal
    pestas_color="DarkGrey"
    ventana_principal=Tk()
    ventana_principal.geometry("300x250")#DIMENSIONES DE LA VENTANA
    ventana_principal.title("Login con tkinter")#TITULO DE LA VENTANA
    Label(text="Escoja su opción", bg="LightGreen", width="300", height="2", font=("Calibri", 13)).pack()#ETIQUETA CON TEXTO
    Label(text="").pack()
    Button(text="Acceder", height="2", width="30", bg=pestas_color, command=login).pack() #BOTÓN "Acceder"
    Label(text="").pack()
    Button(text="Registrarse", height="2", width="30", bg=pestas_color, command=registro).pack() #BOTÓN "Registrarse".
    Label(text="").pack()
    ventana_principal.mainloop()

#CREAMOS VENTANA PARA REGISTRO.
def registro():
    global ventana_registro
    ventana_registro = Toplevel(ventana_principal)
    ventana_registro.title("Registro")
    ventana_registro.geometry("300x250")
 
    global nombre_usuario
    global clave
    global entrada_nombre
    global entrada_clave
    nombre_usuario = StringVar() #DECLARAMOS "string" COMO TIPO DE DATO PARA "nombre_usuario"
    clave = StringVar() #DECLARAMOS "sytring" COMO TIPO DE DATO PARA "clave"
 
    Label(ventana_registro, text="Introduzca datos", bg="LightGreen").pack()
    Label(ventana_registro, text="").pack()
    etiqueta_nombre = Label(ventana_registro, text="Nombre de usuario * ")
    etiqueta_nombre.pack()
    entrada_nombre = Entry(ventana_registro, textvariable=nombre_usuario) #ESPACIO PARA INTRODUCIR EL NOMBRE.
    entrada_nombre.pack()
    etiqueta_clave = Label(ventana_registro, text="Contraseña * ")
    etiqueta_clave.pack()
    entrada_clave = Entry(ventana_registro, textvariable=clave, show='*') #ESPACIO PARA INTRODUCIR LA CONTRASEÑA.
    entrada_clave.pack()
    Label(ventana_registro, text="").pack()
    Button(ventana_registro, text="Registrarse", width=10, height=1, bg="LightGreen", command = registro_usuario).pack() #BOTÓN "Registrarse"

#CREAMOS VENTANA PARA LOGIN.

def login():
    global ventana_login
    ventana_login = Toplevel(ventana_principal)
    ventana_login.title("Acceso a la cuenta")
    ventana_login.geometry("300x250")
    Label(ventana_login, text="Introduzca nombre de usuario y contraseña").pack()
    Label(ventana_login, text="").pack()
 
    global verifica_usuario
    global verifica_clave
 
    verifica_usuario = StringVar()
    verifica_clave = StringVar()
 
    global entrada_login_usuario
    global entrada_login_clave
 
    Label(ventana_login, text="Nombre usuario * ").pack()
    entrada_login_usuario = Entry(ventana_login, textvariable=verifica_usuario)
    entrada_login_usuario.pack()
    Label(ventana_login, text="").pack()
    Label(ventana_login, text="Contraseña * ").pack()
    entrada_login_clave = Entry(ventana_login, textvariable=verifica_clave, show= '*')
    entrada_login_clave.pack()
    Label(ventana_login, text="").pack()
    Button(ventana_login, text="Acceder", width=10, height=1, command = verifica_login).pack()

#VENTANA "VERIFICACION DE LOGIN".

def verifica_login():
    usuario1 = verifica_usuario.get()
    clave1 = verifica_clave.get()
    entrada_login_usuario.delete(0, END) #BORRA INFORMACIÓN DEL CAMPO "Nombre usuario *" AL MOSTRAR NUEVA VENTANA.
    entrada_login_clave.delete(0, END) #BORRA INFORMACIÓN DEL CAMPO "Contraseña *" AL MOSTRAR NUEVA VENTANA.
 
    lista_archivos = os.listdir() #GENERA LISTA DE ARCHIVOS UBICADOS EN EL DIRECTORIO.
    #SI EL NOMBRE SE ENCUENTRA EN LA LISTA DE ARCHIVOS..
    if usuario1 in lista_archivos:
        archivo1 = open(usuario1, "r") #APERTURA DE ARCHIVO EN MODO LECTURA
        verifica = archivo1.read().splitlines() #LECTURA DEL ARCHIVO QUE CONTIENE EL nombre Y contraseña.
        #SI LA CONTRASEÑA INTRODUCIDA SE ENCUENTRA EN EL ARCHIVO...
        if clave1 in verifica:
            exito_login() #...EJECUTAR FUNCIÓN "exito_login()"
        #SI LA CONTRASEÑA NO SE ENCUENTRA EN EL ARCHIVO....
        else:
            no_clave() #...EJECUTAR "no_clave()"
    else:
        no_usuario() #..EJECUTA "no_usuario()".


# VENTANA "Login finalizado con exito".
 
def exito_login():
    global ventana_exito
    ventana_exito = Toplevel(ventana_login)
    ventana_exito.title("Exito")
    ventana_exito.geometry("150x100")
    Label(ventana_exito, text="Login finalizado con exito").pack()
    Button(ventana_exito, text="OK", command=borrar_exito_login).pack()
    

 
#VENTANA DE "Contraseña incorrecta".
 
def no_clave():
    global ventana_no_clave
    ventana_no_clave = Toplevel(ventana_login)
    ventana_no_clave.title("ERROR")
    ventana_no_clave.geometry("150x100")
    Label(ventana_no_clave, text="Contraseña incorrecta ").pack()
    Button(ventana_no_clave, text="OK", command=borrar_no_clave).pack() #EJECUTA "borrar_no_clave()".
 
#VENTANA DE "Usuario no encontrado".
 
def no_usuario():
    global ventana_no_usuario
    ventana_no_usuario = Toplevel(ventana_login)
    ventana_no_usuario.title("ERROR")
    ventana_no_usuario.geometry("150x100")
    Label(ventana_no_usuario, text="Usuario no encontrado").pack()
    Button(ventana_no_usuario, text="OK", command=borrar_no_usuario).pack() #EJECUTA "borrar_no_usuario()"

#CERRADO DE VENTANAS

def borrar_exito_login():
    ventana_exito.destroy()
 
 
def borrar_no_clave():
    ventana_no_clave.destroy()
 
 
def borrar_no_usuario():
    ventana_no_usuario.destroy()

#REGISTRO USUARIO
 
def registro_usuario():
 
    usuario_info = nombre_usuario.get()
    clave_info = clave.get()
 
    file = open(usuario_info, "w") #CREACION DE ARCHIVO CON "nombre" y "clave"
    file.write(usuario_info + "\n")
    file.write(clave_info)
    file.close()
 
    entrada_nombre.delete(0, END)
    entrada_clave.delete(0, END)
 
    Label(ventana_registro, text="Registro completado con éxito", fg="green", font=("calibri", 11)).pack()
 
 
  #EJECUCIÓN DE LA VENTANA DE INICIO.

i really don't know how to solve this on my own, ig bc i don't have the enough knowledge. i want my program to open if the login is succesful
